# How to render html code from database table in Tableau

Tags: html, database, tableau-api

I wanted to know if it is possible to use html and render in tableau.
I am pulling data from a database table which has below columns:

```
Country | HTML
US      | <p> this is a paragraph</P>
UK      | <table><tr><td>sample1</td></tr>
        | <tr><td>sample2</td></tr></table>
IN      | <ul>list1</ul><ul>list2<ul>
```

I want to render this HTML information in tableau
How I can do so?

I am using Tableau desktop currently and soon will switch to Tableau online.